# Opening program via Ollydbg/Immunity in Win7 causes exception unless in XP Compatibility Mode

Tags: windows, ollydbg, immunity-debugger, exception

When opening the reverseme included with [Lena's tutorials](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.2876) for debugging in either Immunity or Ollydbg an exception is produced within ntdll that results in termination of the process with code `4000001E`.  If I configure the executable for a compatibility mode of Windows XP (Service Pack 3) within the file properties then this exception does not occur and the binary executes as expected.  The executable does not produce an exception when running with a debugger attached.

What is the root cause of this exception, and how would I determine it?

Comment: What version of OllyDbg are you using? Does this problem still occur with the latest version (2.01)?

Comment: It happens in both Ollydbg 1.10 and Immunity 1.85.  I'll try it with 2.01 and post back.

Comment: funny fact: I've had a similar problem, and switching to XP (SP3) actually **did** work... there's something fishy going on with Win7 debugger support I suppose.

Comment: Although I'm not entirely sure this is the case, I've stumbled upon [this](http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=176487) while searching for an answer... it seems that it can be caused by 64-bit/32-bit clash in the debugger. Which version of Win7 are you using? It seems that switching to XP compat. forces 32-bit compatibility, while, for some reason, in native Win7 64-bit even 32-bit apps can (?) sometimes switch to 64-bit code in debugger, resulting in nasty things.